# Windows phone xaml Grid Holding event not firing

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8.1

I have a view with ListView which ItemTemplate has Grid in it, I am listening to `Holding` event in order to show some flyout when user Holds one of the ListView items:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemListViewItemTemplate">
            <Grid 
                x:Name="ListViewItemBaseGrid" 
                Holding="OnChat_Holding">
             ......
```

However this event not fires from time to time, I mean 9 out of 10 times it works perfectly but once a while the event isn't raised , and by that I am not able to show the flyout that I want to show...

Is there a better solution for this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemListViewItemTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="ListViewItemBaseGrid"
          Background="Transparent"
          Holding="OnChat_Holding">
```

Comment: How Background set to Transparent will solve this issue? Please explain :)

Comment: It's all about hit test area. Without background holding will only work on content of grid but not on the entire grid

Comment: OK, I'll try. Thank you!